# How to open a file with the default CSV editor in Windows Forms?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winforms, csv, c++-cli

I have this backup program I am working on that uses Windows Forms for the design.
All is working well except for one button so I will spare the entire code.
I have one Button that allows the user to open a `CSV` file from a certain location to edit in their default CSV editor program (i.e., Excel, Libre etc.) and the Button works fine as this:

```
private: System::Void button17_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
String^ CSVLoc = textBox1->Text;
string CSVLoc1 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(CSVLoc);
system(("start " + CSVLoc1 + "\\SystemIPs.csv").c_str());
}
```

However, I would like to avoid using the **system** function as I do not like that it flashes a command window when launching the default editor program.

I have tried:

```
private: System::Void button17_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
String^ CSVLoc = textBox1->Text;
string CSVLoc1 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(CSVLoc);
WinExec(("start " + CSVLoc1 + "\\SystemIPs.csv").c_str(), SW_HIDE);
}
```

but that does nothing when I click the button.
`WinExec` worked as a replacement for my other System function commands but not here.

The function of the button is not to do any editing from my program so the need to read or write to it is not necessary.  Just need it to open in the default editor without a command window popup.

I've searched for hours to try to find a solution with no luck.
I am open to any suggestion here even if it is using the system function but something niffy way to hide that I am not aware of at this time.

The program is designed for Windows only and set to run as a Windows Application. Using CLR and .Net is 4.7.2.  As I mention everything works well, just trying to find a way to hide that pesky command window popup.

Comment: `String^ csvLoc = textBox1->Text; Process::Start(Path::Combine(csvLoc, "SystemIPs.csv"));` -- You should specify the .Net version in use.

Comment: You could also see: [Launching Applications (ShellExecute, ShellExecuteEx, SHELLEXECUTEINFO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch) (what's been used here under the hood).

Comment: Jimi, Process::Start appears to be undefined.  I tried ShellExecute following the examples in the link and it rejects my verb "open" and my file path stating "argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type" for both the verb and the path.

Comment: The Process class is part of System::Diagnostics, so add `using namespace System::Diagnostics;`. The Path class requires `using namespace System::IO;`. All come from the `mscorlib.dll` assembly that is added to the Project's References by default.

Comment: Hey Jimi, as stated in my comment to Jack, it works perfectly.  Thanks for the help and teaching me something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jimi said, you could use Process.Start Method to open a csv file with the default editor.

First, please add namespace reference.

```
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
```

Second, you could try the following code to open it.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        String^ str = textBox1->Text;
        Process::Start(str);
    }
```